# SQL query to get duration of datetime ranges minus break time ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In SQL Server 2019, I have a table `Runs` that contains time ranges with start datetime column in UTC and an end datetime column in UTC.

I have another table, `BreakSchedule`, of break time ranges in the format start time local to end time local.

Given a time zone as a SQL parameter, I want to select multiple rows from the first table (Runs) and get the total duration in minutes from the start UTC datetime column to the end UTC datetime column MINUS any break times whose time zone-adjusted times fall within the range for that particular time range.

Here is an example:

```
create table Runs 
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    dtStartTimeUtc datetime not null,
    dtEndTimeUtc datetime not null,
    nExpectedMinutes int not null
);

create table BreakSchedule 
(
    tStartTimeLocal time not null,
    tEndTimeLocal time not null
);

insert into BreakSchedule (tStartTimeLocal, tEndTimeLocal)
values ('08:30:00', '08:40:00'), ('09:30:00', '10:30:00'), 
       ('17:00:00', '18:00:00'), ('23:30:00', '00:30:00');

/*
  Equivalent in UTC if local time zone is Central Standard Time
  13:30-13:40, 14:30-15:30, 22:00-23:00, 04:30-05:30
*/

insert into Runs (dtStartTimeUtc, dtEndTimeUtc, nExpectedMinutes)
values
  ('2023-10-02 12:00:00', '2023-10-02 13:30:00', 90),
  ('2023-10-02 13:00:00', '2023-10-02 13:35:00', 30),
  ('2023-10-02 13:35:00', '2023-10-02 14:00:00', 20),
  ('2023-10-02 14:15:00', '2023-10-03 05:15:00', 735),
  ('2023-10-02 14:30:00', '2023-10-02 15:00:00', 0)
```

Starting point for query I can't figure out how to finish:

```
declare @tz varchar(100) = 'Central Standard Time';

select 
    *, 'should be same value as nExpectedMinutes' [actualminutes]
from  
    Runs
```

The above code also in SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42fdd/11

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Fiddles are great - but questions need to be self contained, so you need to add the contents of your fiddle to your question also.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code into the question

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Runs TABLE (id int identity(1,1) primary key, dtStartTimeUtc datetimeoffset not null, dtEndTimeUtc datetimeoffset not null, nExpectedMinutes int not null);
DECLARE @BreakSchedule TABLE (tStartTimeLocal time not null, tEndTimeLocal time not null);
insert into @BreakSchedule (tStartTimeLocal, tEndTimeLocal) values 
('08:30:00', '08:40:00'), ('09:30:00', '10:30:00'), ('17:00:00', '18:00:00'), ('23:30:00', '00:30:00');

/*
  Equivalent in UTC if local time zone is Central Standard Time
  13:30-13:40, 14:30-15:30, 22:00-23:00, 04:30-05:30
*/

insert into @Runs (dtStartTimeUtc, dtEndTimeUtc, nExpectedMinutes) values
('2023-10-02 12:00:00', '2023-10-02 13:30:00', 90),  ('2023-10-02 13:00:00', '2023-10-02 13:35:00', 30),  ('2023-10-02 13:35:00', '2023-10-02 14:00:00', 20),  ('2023-10-02 14:15:00', '2023-10-03 05:15:00', 735),  ('2023-10-02 14:30:00', '2023-10-02 15:00:00', 0);

DECLARE @tz NVARCHAR(50) = 'Central Standard Time'

SELECT r.id, r.dtStartTimeUtc, r.dtEndTimeUtc, r.nExpectedMinutes, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,b.tStartTimeLocal, b.tEndTimeLocal)) AS breakMinutes
  FROM @Runs r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @BreakSchedule b
      ON b.tStartTimeLocal BETWEEN CAST(r.dtStartTimeUtc AT TIME ZONE @tz AS TIME) AND CAST(r.dtEndTimeUtc AT TIME ZONE @tz  AS TIME)
 GROUP BY r.id, r.dtStartTimeUtc, r.dtEndTimeUtc, r.nExpectedMinutes;
```

Thanks for providing the DDL/DML!
I modified your datatypes to change the `DATETIME` in **Runs** to `DATETIMEOFFSET`. This could be done as a cast inline, if you can't modify the columns.

With a `DATETIMEOFFSET` we can make use of the `AT TIME ZONE` modifier to adjust the time zone of the datetime, using the standard time zone names.

From there, we can join the **BreakSchedule** table, with an inline cast to `TIME` and collect up the break minutes. I summed the break minutes in the event a run spanned more than one of them.

| id | dtStartTimeUtc | dtEndTimeUtc | nExpectedMinutes | breakMinutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-02 12:00:00.0000000 +00:00 | 2023-10-02 13:30:00.0000000 +00:00 | 90 | 10 |
| 2 | 2023-10-02 13:00:00.0000000 +00:00 | 2023-10-02 13:35:00.0000000 +00:00 | 30 | 10 |
| 3 | 2023-10-02 13:35:00.0000000 +00:00 | 2023-10-02 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00 | 20 |  |
| 4 | 2023-10-02 14:15:00.0000000 +00:00 | 2023-10-03 05:15:00.0000000 +00:00 | 735 |  |
| 5 | 2023-10-02 14:30:00.0000000 +00:00 | 2023-10-02 15:00:00.0000000 +00:00 | 0 | 60 |

`DATETIMEOFFSET` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

`AT TIME ZONE` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The results are incorrect. Run ID 1 should have 0 breakMinutes. Run ID 2 should have 5 breakMinutes. Unless my manual human math is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to account for break times that are not fully encompassed by a run.
ID 1 matches as it starts at 08:30

Comment: In addition, there is complexity involving runs (or breaktimes) that span midnight. I am using your response as a starting point though, so thanks for the `datetimeoffset` info.

Comment: To be fair Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. My intent is to give you enough to solve the specific problem, not provide a fully fleshed out solution :).
Getting passed midnight breaks will probably need you to split them into before midnight and after midnight segments, since they're "local" you could just do that in the data, maybe?